# Canadian Industrial Data i.e. NAICS

Tags: data-request, government, research, business, canada

I know that any time you register a business in Canada, you have to classify the business with respect to the [North American Industry Classification System](https://www23.statcan.gc.ca/imdb/p3VD.pl?Function=getVD&TVD=1181553) ([NAICS](https://www23.statcan.gc.ca/imdb/p3VD.pl?Function=getVD&TVD=1181553)).

I am interested in knowing how populated certain industries are. But for some reason I cannot figure out how to access the data in the NAICS.

Does anybody know where one can access such data?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I finally found the way to access it...

https://www.ic.gc.ca/app/scr/app/cis/search-recherche?lang=eng